# How do Perl Cwd::cwd and Cwd::getcwd functions differ?

Tags: working-directory, perl, getcwd

## The question

What is the difference between `Cwd::cwd` and `Cwd::getcwd` in Perl, generally, without regard to any specific platform? Why does Perl have both? What is the intended use, which one should I use in which scenarios? (Example use cases will be appreciated.) Does it matter? (Assuming I don’t mix them.) Does choice of either one affect portability in any way? Which one is more commonly used in modules?

Even if I interpret the manual is saying that except for corner cases `cwd` is `` `pwd` `` and `getcwd` just calls `getcwd` from `unistd.h`, what is the actual difference? This works only on POSIX systems, anyway.

I can always read the implementation but that tells me nothing about the meaning of those functions. Implementation details may change, not so defined meaning. (Otherwise a breaking change occurs, which is serious business.)

## What does the manual say

Quoting Perl’s [Cwd module manpage](http://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd.html):

> Each of these functions are called without arguments and return the absolute path of the current working directory.
>
> - getcwd
>
>   `my $cwd = getcwd();`
>
>   Returns the current working directory.
>
>   Exposes the POSIX function getcwd(3) or re-implements it if it's not available.
> - cwd
>
>   `my $cwd = cwd();`
>
>   The cwd() is the most natural form for the current architecture. For most systems it is identical to `pwd` (but without the trailing line terminator).

And in the Notes section:

> - Actually, on Mac OS, the `getcwd()`, `fastgetcwd()` and `fastcwd()` functions are all aliases for the `cwd()` function, which, on Mac OS, calls `pwd`. Likewise, the `abs_path()` function is an alias for `fast_abs_path()`

OK, I know that on Mac OS<sup>1</sup> there is no difference between `getcwd()` and `cwd()` as both actually boil down to `` `pwd` ``. But what on other platforms? (*I’m especially interested in Debian Linux.*)

---

<sup>1</sup> Classic Mac OS, not OS X. `$^O` values are `MacOS` and `darwin` for Mac OS and OS X, respectively. *Thanks, [@tobyink](/users/1990570/tobyink) and [@ikegami](/users/589924/ikegami).*

<sub>And a little meta-question: How to avoid asking similar questions for other modules with very similar functions? Is there a universal way of discovering the difference, other than digging through the implementation? (*Currently, I think that if the documentation is not clear about intended use and differences, I have to ask someone more experienced or read the implementation myself.*)</sub>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Generally speaking

I think the idea is that `cwd()` always resolves to the external, OS-specific way of getting the current working directory. That is, running `pwd` on Linux, `command /c cd` on DOS, `/usr/bin/fullpath -t` in QNX, and so on — all examples are from actual `Cwd.pm`. The `getcwd()` is supposed to use the POSIX system call if it is available, and falls back to the `cwd()` if not.

Why we have both? In the current implementation I believe exporting just `getcwd()` would be enough for most of systems, but who knows why the logic of “if syscall is available, use it, else run `cwd()`” can fail on some system (e.g. [on MorphOS in Perl 5.6.1](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2004/08/msg94261.html)).

## On Linux

On Linux, `cwd()` will run `` `/bin/pwd` `` (will actually execute the binary and get its output), while `getcwd()` will issue `getcwd(2)` system call.

### Actual effect inspected via `strace`

One can use `strace(1)` to see that in action:

Using `cwd()`:

```
$ strace -f perl -MCwd -e 'cwd(); ' 2>&1 | grep execve
execve("/usr/bin/perl", ["perl", "-MCwd", "-e", "cwd(); "], [/* 27 vars */]) = 0
[pid 31276] execve("/bin/pwd", ["/bin/pwd"], [/* 27 vars */] <unfinished ...>
[pid 31276] <... execve resumed> )      = 0
```

Using `getcwd()`:

```
$ strace -f perl -MCwd -e 'getcwd(); ' 2>&1 | grep execve
execve("/usr/bin/perl", ["perl", "-MCwd", "-e", "getcwd(); "], [/* 27 vars */]) = 0
```

### Reading `Cwd.pm` source

You can take a look at the sources ([`Cwd.pm`](https://metacpan.org/source/SMUELLER/PathTools-3.47/Cwd.pm), e.g. in CPAN) and see that for Linux `cwd()` call is mapped to `_backtick_pwd` which, as the name suggests, calls the `pwd` in backticks.

Here is a snippet from `Cwd.pm`, with my comments:

```
unless ($METHOD_MAP{$^O}{cwd} or defined &cwd) {
    ...
    # some logic to find the pwd binary here, $found_pwd_cmd is set to 1 on Linux
    ...
    if( $os eq 'MacOS' || $found_pwd_cmd )
    {
        *cwd = \&_backtick_pwd;  # on Linux we actually go here
    }
    else {
        *cwd = \&getcwd;
    }
}
```

### Performance benchmark

Finally, the difference between two is that `cwd()`, which calls another binary, must be slower. We can make some kind of a performance test:

```
$ time perl -MCwd -e 'for (1..10000) { cwd(); }'

real    0m7.177s
user    0m0.380s
sys     0m1.440s
```

Now compare it with the system call:

```
$ time perl -MCwd -e 'for (1..10000) { getcwd(); }'

real    0m0.018s
user    0m0.009s
sys     0m0.008s
```

### Discussion, choice

But as you don't usually query the current working directory too often, both options will work — unless you cannot spawn any more processes for some reason related to `ulimit`, out of memory situation, etc.

Finally, as for selecting which one to use: for Linux, I would always use `getcwd()`. I suppose you will need to make your tests and select which function to use if you are going to write a portable piece of code that will run on some really strange platform (here, of course, Linux, OS X, and Windows are not in the list of strange platforms).

Comment: Interesting that even in the Perl5 porters Usenet group (the thread about problem with MorphOS you link to), the developers have no clue if it is OK to make `getcwd()` an alias of `cwd()`. It seems to work, but nobody can be sure. I don’t expect a better answer here, so I accept this. If one actually arrived, I’d reconsider. Also if you find anything relevant to add, please include it in your answer (as I did with your comments).