# Why fall back to cwd() if getcwd() does not have access?

Tags: perl

The [`FindBin`](https://metacpan.org/pod/FindBin) module determines the current working directory at compile time using this function (see source code [here](https://metacpan.org/source/SHAY/perl-5.22.1/lib/FindBin.pm)):

```
sub cwd2 {
   my $cwd = getcwd();
   # getcwd might fail if it hasn't access to the current directory.
   # try harder.
   defined $cwd or $cwd = cwd();
   $cwd;
}
```

where `cwd()` and `getcwd()` are both imported from the [`Cwd`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cwd) module. In which cases would `getcwd()` fail but `cwd()` still work? ( I am most interested in the Linux platform if that matters )

See also:

- [How do Perl Cwd::cwd and Cwd::getcwd functions differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25219996/2173773)
- [Why you should use getcwd and not cwd](http://www.dagolden.com/index.php/2312/why-you-should-use-getcwd-and-not-cwd/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the comment says, `getcwd()` can fail if the process doesn't have enough access to the current directory (and all its ancestors). `cwd()` has the potential to shell out to a possibly-setuid external `pwd` command and get the directory even in that case.

More generally, `getcwd()` is documented to behave like the POSIX `getcwd` call. `cwd()` is documented as being more flexible. The difference between them will likely be very small on Linux, but both the `Cwd` and `FindBin` modules are intended to work on all the platforms that Perl support. Those include Windows, VMS, pre-OSX MacOS, IBM z/OS and a bucketload of others. On those, the difference between the commands may well be significant.